# Integrating AJAX with mailchimp

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to integrate AJAX with a mailchimp form. I’ve followed another member’s answer but still cannot get it to work. Could you guys see what's wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
<form id="form">
  <script>
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
    formData = {
        u: "xxxxxxxxx",
        id: "xxxxxxxxx"
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/post-json?",
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            //action
        },
        error: function() {
           //action
        }
    });
    });
  </script>

<fieldset>
    <label for="email_input_id"><input placeholder=
    "Type Your Email" type="email" /></label>
</fieldset><button type= "submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You're making a GET request so setting a content type makes no sense. Make sure the request endpoint supports CORS.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my code working.

```
 <form id="form" action="https://xxxxx.com/subscribe/post-json?u=xxxxx&id=xxxx&c=?" method="GET">
      <input type="hidden" name="u" value="xxxx">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="xxxx">
      <input type="EMAIL" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" 
             name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" size="25" value="" 
             placeholder="Type your email and press enter">
      <p id="response"> </p>
 </form>

      <script>
          $('#form').submit(function(e) {
          var $this = $(this);
          var paragraph = document.getElementById('response');

          $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "https://xxx.com/subscribe/post-json?u=xx&id=xx&c=?",
          data: $this.serialize(),
          dataType    : 'json',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          error       : function(err) { alert("Could not connect to the registration server."); },
          success     : function(data) {
              if (data.result != "success") {
                     paragraph.innerHTML = data.msg;
              } else {
                      paragraph.innerHTML = data.msg;
                      }
              }
             });
           return false;
           });
      </script>
```